# Return object with subset of its attributes

Tags: javascript

I've got a flat JavaScript object like this:

```
{ 
  id: 3726492,
  kind: 'user',
  permalink: 'nicholas',
  username: 'Nicholas',
  ...
  a lot more attributes
}
```

I'd like to create a new object which only has a subset of the attributes of the original object.

Something like

```
var newObject = oldObject.fields(['id', 'username']);
```

newObject would be

```
{ 
  id: 3726492,
  username: 'Nicholas'
}
```

**Is there already something like this?**

Comment: I don't think it exists in vanilla, no. As for helper libraries, there's sure to be at least one doing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```js
function pick(data, keys) {
  var result = {};
  
  keys.forEach(function (key) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result[key] = data[key];
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}

var data = { 
  id: 3726492,
  kind: 'user',
  permalink: 'nicholas',
  username: 'Nicholas'
}

var newData = pick(data, ['id', 'kind']);
console.log(newData);
```

In *underscorejs* or *lodash* there is method [`.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick)

```js
var data = { 
  id: 3726492,
  kind: 'user',
  permalink: 'nicholas',
  username: 'Nicholas',
};

var newObject = _.pick(data, 'id', 'username');
console.log(newObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to reduce one object to another using the list of properties:

```js
function subset(obj, propList) {
  return propList.reduce(function(newObj, prop) {
    obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && (newObj[prop] = obj[prop]);
    return newObj;
  }, {});
}

var obj = { 
  id: 3726492,
  kind: 'user',
  permalink: 'nicholas',
  username: 'Nicholas'
};

var newObj = subset(obj, ['id', 'username']);
console.log(newObj);
document.getElementById('json').innerText = JSON.stringify(newObj);
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not built-in, but you can sure define a simple function that does the job:

```
var original = {a:1112, b:434, c:666, d:222};

function fieldSubset(obj, fields) {
  var subsetClone = {};
  for( var i=0,l=fields.length; i<l; i++) {
    // This can prevent filling undefined as properties
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(fields[i])) {
      subsetClone[fields[i]] = obj[fields[i]];
    }
  }
  return subsetClone;
}

fieldSubset(original, ["a", "c"]);
```

You can also use this in `Object.prototype`, but be aware that this might happen to conflict with native API in the future versions of JavaScript:

```
var original = {a:1112, b:434, c:666, d:222};
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "fieldSubset", { 
  value: function(fields) {
      var subsetClone = {};
      for( var i=0,l=fields.length; i<l; i++) {
        // This can prevent filling undefined as properties
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(fields[i])) {
          subsetClone[fields[i]] = this[fields[i]];
        }
      }
      return subsetClone;
    },
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true}
);  
original.fieldSubset(["a", "c"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). We are also using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). The idea is to keep extending a blank object with the keys found in the filters array. If you see, the reduce function takes a callback function with arg1,arg2,arg3 params as the first argument and an empty object as the second argument. This object will be cloned and extended with the help of the keys specified in the filters array.

```js
var a = { 
  id: 3726492,
  kind: 'user',
  permalink: 'nicholas',
  username: 'Nicholas',
};

var filters = ["id","username","permalink"];

var sub = Object.keys(a).reduce((arg1,arg2,arg3)=>{  var res = {}; if(filters.indexOf(arg2)>=0){  res[arg2] = a[arg2]; } return Object.assign(arg1,res);},{})

console.log(sub);
```

Comment: One-liners can be so powerful

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specifically mentioned what is the type of values behind your object's keys. Your current answers cover the shallow copy and deep copy. 
Another alternative would be to create a view of the original object. This would be helpful if you have very large data objects and you do not want them copy in the memory.

```
function View(obj, properties) {
  var view = {};
  properties.forEach(function(prop) {
    Object.defineProperty(view, prop, {
      get: function() {
             return obj[prop];
           },
      set: function(val) {
             obj[prop] = val;
           },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
  });
  return view;
}
```

then with your data you can do:

```
var data = { 
  id: 3726492,
  kind: 'user',
  permalink: 'nicholas',
  username: 'Nicholas',
},
view = new View(data, ['id', 'username']);
view.id; // 3736492
view.username; // Nicholas
```

of course you have to be aware that you can change your original object just by `view.id = 'something else'`. However it is easily preventable.